# What is best left for Types to handle as opposed to manually checking?

Tags: typescript, types, type-safety

I'm trying to come up with a really good analogy (to explain to a child) for why Type-safety (such as what TypeScript does), is really really good..

I've been thinking along the lines of those circle or square holes which kids have in their toys, that allow them to only put shapes through which are of a certain 'type'..

I'm also trying to come up with a good analogy for not using type-safety, could we say that it is like a dam which 'allows water through' and the parameters determine the water pressure allowed?

Thanks!

Comment: How about "do you know those Disneyland rides where it says you need to be this tall to ride and there's a bar to measure yourself so that the park can make sure the ride is safe for everyone?"

Comment: That's good, but does the typesafety stop dogs going in, or does it stop people under a certain height going in? I guess for people under a certain height, you would have to use composability to add 'isAbove1Metre' to a person type? Otherwise you have to do a 'check height' as the first part of the function call right (and doesn't that beat the objective of type safety)?

Comment: There's also a worker there that makes sure no dogs go in. :-)

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around what should be handled by using a type, and what should be handled by using parameters (obviously types can be avoided if you do a lot of manual checking yourself)

Comment: Actually here's another thought: http://blog.wolksoftware.com/contributing-to-definitelytyped on the line beginning with "I can also see that the withSideEffect".. the writer talks about creating a definitions file for a js project.. the code they reference has a `typeof ===` check in it.. can this safely be removed when using typescript, or is it good to have as a backup too?

Comment: Type safety moves validation into the type system, and thus into the compiler esther than the runtime check. Maybe the analog would be giving people different color wrist bands at the entrance, then the "runtime check" at the ride becomes unnecessary (this analogy is falling a bit apart here). For TS specifically one has to keep in mind that it's easy to lie to the compiler (unlike many other languages), but your question isn't even really about TS, specifically (it's also likely to be closed but I'm not gonna be the one voting for that).

Comment: I've rephrased the question to make it more palatable to those who think in just binary. Thanks for being open minded enough not to vote to close. And thanks for the help.

Comment: When you go to the hardware store to buy a hinge for your door, do you just buy the first one that you see in the store hoping that it will fit, or do you find the one that matches your door's specifications and buy *that* one?  Which approach is most efficient?

Comment: Ok, nice analogy, so if I was to code that up, I would be creating a `Door` class, which would then implement `SizeElevenHinges` class? At the hardware store, I would then find another 'brand' of hinges which also implemented `SizeElevenHinges`?

Comment: Uh, no.  It's not that exact of a metaphor.  It's meant to describe the simple idea that type checking can be done at compile time instead of run time.  That's the reason compile-time types exist in the first place.